# Lifetime issues while balancing brackets

Tags: rust, borrowing

I'm facing issues with lifetimes. The implementation should balance three kinds of brackets: `(`, `[`, and `{`. I'm using a stack for it but running into some issues.

```
pub struct Brackets {
    stack: Vec<char>,
}

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Brackets {
    fn from(input: &str) -> Self {
        let mut stack: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
        for c in input.chars() {
            stack.push(c);
        }

        Brackets { stack }
    }
}

impl<'a> Brackets {
    pub fn are_balanced(&self) -> bool {
        let mut stack = Vec::new();
        for c in &self.stack {
            // Converts the character to a String to a &str... Feels dumb
            let slice = &c.to_string()[..];
            match slice {
                "(" | "[" | "{" => stack.push(slice),
                ")" | "]" | "}" => {
                    let popped = stack.pop();
                    match popped {
                        Some(")") => {
                            if slice != "(" {
                                return false;
                            };
                        }
                        Some("]") => {
                            if slice != "[" {
                                return false;
                            };
                        }
                        Some("}") => {
                            if slice != "{" {
                                return false;
                            };
                        }
                        _ => return false,
                    }
                }
                _ => continue,
            }
        }

        true
    }
}
```

I want to push an opening bracket, and pop a closing bracket. If a closing bracket does not match an opening bracket, the brackets are not balanced. Any non-bracket input I ignore.

The issue I'm having:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:26
   |
21 |             let slice = &c.to_string()[..];
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
...
47 |         }
   |         - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
...
50 |     }
   |     - temporary value needs to live until here
```

I understand that the stack in the `are_balanced(&self)` function lives longer than the `slice` variable I'm pushing into the stack. How can I get around this?  I've tried changing the type of the stacks to `&'a str` and put a lifetime on the `Brackets` struct but have not succeeded. A guess is that it could be solved by using owned `String`s everywhere, but it seems unnecessarily expensive and I'd really like to see a solution to this..

Comment: *Converts the character to a String to a &str* — but why?

Comment: @Shepmaster Don't know how to convert a char to a &str otherwise

Comment: @SimonCarlson but why do you need to convert in the first place?

Comment: When pushing the char into the stack, I get the error "expected char, found str" for instance when matching ```"(" | "[" | "{" => stack.push(c)```. I did not find a way to create or compare with char literals, hence tried going for string slices instead, and now I'm at this stage.

Comment: `"("` is indeed a string literal, if you want a `char` literal, you should use `'('`

Comment: @mcarton That solves a lot of issues. For the sake of learning though, say we have a stack with string slices, how can one deal with the lifetime issues posed in the question?

Comment: If you had a stack with string slices, you wouldn't have lifetime issues because you could `match` against each slice directly with no conversion: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6e2e0e6e30bc750ee02206d34876b9ef&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to confuse a string literal `"("` with a `char` literal `'('`. If you replace all string literals, your code works:

```
for &c in &self.stack {
    match c {
        '(' | '[' | '{' => stack.push(c),
        ')' | ']' | '}' => {
            let popped = stack.pop();
            match popped {
                Some(')') => {
                    if c != '(' {
                        return false;
                    };
                }
                Some(']') => {
                    if c != '[' {
                        return false;
                    };
                }
                Some('}') => {
                    if c != '{' {
                        return false;
                    };
                }
                _ => return false,
            }
        }
        _ => continue,
    }
}
```

Rust, unlike for example Python or Bash, has a different type for `char` and for strings. It is slightly misleading though, as it doesn't really represent a character, but rather a Unicode scalar value. Some things that you would consider a character are not actually representable by a `char` (e.g. lots of emojis, or some accentuated letters like `ɔ̃`). This means that you might want to think twice whether to use `char`s or strings for some applications. For the purpose of balancing brackets however, it's perfectly fine to use `char`; I don't expect even fancy Unicode brackets to not have their own scalar value.

Note that I have also have changed the loop to use `&c`, this is because iterating the stack would yield references to its elements (so `&char` in our case), but that's slightly inconvenient in this case. Using `&c` makes sure that `c` itself is a `char` (`&c: &char` <=> `c: char`).

As for the follow-up question

> say we have a stack with string slices, how can one deal with the lifetime issues

Well, that would depend exactly on why the string would need to be saved (which we have seen to not be necessary).

As the problem comes from trying to store a reference to a temporary string (the `c.to_string()` in your code), you could store owned `String`s instead (you've already allocated them anyways).